# bash function or script to execute command in multiple directories

Tags: bash

I want to have command that would execute command in arguments in `dir1` and `dir2`

tests

```
# put this in our .bashrc
alias gca="git commit -v -a"

my-exec gca
my-exec gca -m "my commit wrapped in double quotes"
my-exec gca -m "my commit wrapped in double quotes with 'something' in single quotes"
my-exec gca -m 'my commit wrapped in single quotes with "something" in double quotes'
```

I have tried

```
my-exec () {
  (cd $HOME/dir1 && eval "$@")
  (cd $HOME/dir2 && eval "$@")
}
```

but it's not working, because

```
# working fine
my-exec gca

# executes
# gca -m my commit wrapped in double quotes
# actually
my-exec gca -m "my commit wrapped in double quotes"

# didnt try
my-exec gca -m "my commit wrapped in double quotes with 'something' in single quotes"

# didnt try
my-exec gca -m 'my commit wrapped in single quotes with "something" in double quotes'
```

---

UPDATE

also tried

```
my-exec () {
  echo "$@"      > /tmp/my-exec
  cat /tmp/my-exec
  (cd $HOME/dir1 && bash -i /tmp/my-exec)
  (cd $HOME/dir2 && bash -i /tmp/my-exec)
}
```

but `echo "$@"` too doesn't preserve quotes

Comment: Remove the `eval`.

Comment: Is the behavior different when you use `eval $@` instead on `eval "$@"` ?

Comment: @akskap `eval $@` is working the same as `eval "$@"`, and thus not applicable to my use case

Comment: @choroba removing `eval` is not executing aliases and thus not applicable to my use case

Comment: [Bash FAQ 050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is relevant, but start by replacing your alias with a function: `gca () { git commit -v -a "$@"; }`. That should at least allow `cd ... && "$@"` to work in `my_exec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `eval` -- it causes many parsing problems, and in this case you shouldn't need it:

```
my-exec () {
  (cd $HOME/dir1 && "$@")
  (cd $HOME/dir2 && "$@")
}
```

You might also run into trouble because `gca` is an alias, and they have a separate set of parsing oddities associated with them. Use a function instead. But be sure to remove the alias definition, or it'll override the function:

```
unalias gca
gca() {
    git commit -v -a "$@"
}
```

If you really really really need to keep `gca` as an alias rather than a function (why?), you will need to use `eval`, but in order to keep that from screwing up complex arguments, you need to re-quote those. Fortunately, you can use bash `printf`'s `%q` format directive to add suitable quoting/escaping to the arguments:

```
my-exec () {
  (cd $HOME/dir1 && "$(printf '%q ' "$@")")
  (cd $HOME/dir2 && "$(printf '%q ' "$@")")
}
```

But really, you should use functions instead of aliases. They have much cleaner syntax and semantics, and (as we're seeing here) work in places where aliases don't.

Comment: `(cd $HOME/dir1 && eval "$(printf '%q ' "$@")")` indeed working